# Benefit of higher version of CUDA for devices with lower Compute Capability

Tags: cuda, version

I'm using CUDA 7.0 on a Tesla K20X (C.C. 3.5). Is there any benefit to update to a higher version of CUDA, say 8.0. Is there any compatibility or stability risk with using higher version of CUDA with devices with (much) lower C.C.?
(Various available versions of CUDA on Nvidia website make me doubtful which one is really good)

Comment: Maybe there are no new (big) features for low CC GPUs but the toolkit also includes programs like nvprof whose new features you will most likely be able to use. And they may also fixed some bugs in the newer version. Nvidia still provides older versions of CUDA because e.g. other libraries may need them. Also really low CCs are not supported by newer CUDA versions (CUDA 7.0 dropped CC 1.x support and afaik CUDA 9.0 will drop support for CC 2.x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding benefits, newer CUDA toolkit versions usually provide feature benefits (new features, and/or enhanced performance) over previous CUDA toolkit version.  However there are also occasionally performance regressions.  Specifics can't be given - it may vary based on your exact code.  However there are generally summary blog articles for each new CUDA toolkit version, for example [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-8-features-revealed/) is the one for CUDA 8 and [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-9-features-revealed/) is the one for CUDA 9, describing the new features available.

Regarding compatibility, there should be no risk to moving to a higher CUDA version, regardless of the compute capability of your device, as long as your device is supported.  All current CUDA versions in the range of 7-9 support your cc3.5 GPU.

Regarding stability, it is possible that a newer CUDA version may have a bug, but it is also possible that a bug in your existing CUDA version may be fixed in a newer version.  Guarantees can't be made here; software almost always has bugs in it.  However it is generally recommended to use the latest CUDA version compatible with your GPU (in the absence of other considerations), as this gives you access the latest features and at least gives you the best possibility that a historically known issue has been addressed.

I doubt these sort of platitudes are any different regardless of the software stack (e.g. compiler, tools framework, etc.) that you are using.  I don't think these considerations are specific or unique to CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using CUDA 7.0 on a Tesla K20X (C.C. 3.5). Is there any benefit to update to a higher version of CUDA, say 8.0 ?

Are you kidding me? There are *enormous* benefits. It's a *world* of difference! Just have a look at the [CUDA 8 feature descriptions](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-8-features-revealed/) (Parallel4All blog entry). Specifically,

#### CUDA 8.0 lets you compile with GCC 5.x instead of 4.x

Not only does that save you a life full of pain having to build your own GCC - since modern distros often don't package it at all, and it's not the system's default compiler. Also, GCC 5.x has [lots of improvements](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html), not the least of which being full C++14 support for host-side code.

#### CUDA 8 lets you use C++11 lambdas in device code

(actually, CUDA 7.5 lets you do that and this is rounded off in CUDA 8)

#### NVCC internal improvements

Not that I can list these, but hopefully NVIDIA continues working on its compiler, equipping it with better optimization logic.

#### Much faster compilation

NVCC is *markedly* faster with CUDA 8. It might be up to 2x, but even if it's just 1.5x - that really improves your quality of life as a developer...

Shall I go on? ... all of the above applies regardless of your compute capability. And CC 3.5 or 3.7 is nothing to sneeze at anyway.